# How to implement the logic of string trim() method

Tags: java, string, trim

I have tried checking the internal implementation of String trim() , but could not get the complete idea.Can any one please explain the internal behaviour of trim() .I know that it removes the whitespaces.But while executing the below program, white spaces are not removed.

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String s = "  abd  c  ";
        String s3 = s.trim();
        System.out.println(s3);
    }
}
```

How to implement the internal logic of trim method...?

Comment: What do you mean _white space are not removed_?

Comment: The space between the characters in the string..

Comment: `trim()` removes whitespace *from either end* (not from within the String)

Comment: @Bohemian: I am asking the internal execution of the trim function..I am not asking what this function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim does not remove spaces among the characters. It only removes from the beginning/end.

Answer (score 1):

`trim` removes leading and trailing blanks. and that is working fine in your example. `trim()` will not delete blanks between other letters in your string.

Answer (score 0):

The `String.trim()` removes whitespace from the ends of the `String` (right and left).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "  abd  c  ";
    System.out.printf("'%s'%n", s);
    String s3 = s.trim();
    System.out.printf("'%s'%n", s3);
}
```

Output is

```
'  abd  c  '
'abd  c'
```

If you want to remove space in the middle of the `String` you could use [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (with the regular expression `"\\s"` to match white-space) like

```
String s2 = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
System.out.printf("'%s'%n", s2);
```

Output is

```
'abdc'
```